# I cannot see interactive mode for the preview when using Jetpack Compose in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 2
I cannot see the interactive mode icon in the preview. Is this version support such option?

I want to be able to interact with the preview (for example click on the buttons) without deploying the apk on the device:

[image]

For now i see only the "Deploy preview" option.
Is there something I am missing to use the interactive mode?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This option is disabled by default on Arctic Fox because is considered experimental. So you must enable it in File > Settings > Experimental (Win) or Android Studio > Preferences > Experimental (Mac OS X)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

### You just need to hover the mouse pointer over the upper right part of the preview

I was unable to find it today too in the newest Android Studio Giraffe, but it turned out to be very simple.

[image: like this]

Comment: This is crazy. Same here I've been looking for this for 3 days haha thanks!

Comment: Spent entirely too long looking for this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know why they had to make it sound like an Easter egg collecting thing

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find the interactive mode at the top right until I disabled the Enable @preview picker option from settings

[image]