# How to enable Interactive Preview button for Jetpack Compose UI in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image: No Interactive Preview Button]

I can't seem to find the **Interactive Preview** button on Android Studio, beside the deploy preview button. I am running Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 3.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After looking around I got to know that Interactive Previews is an experimental feature, at least to the date of this answer. I had to enable it from Android Studio's: File -> Settings -> Experimental -> Enable interactive and animation preview tools. Here is the [Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling?authuser=1#enable-experimental-features) from the android developer website.

[image: After On]

After enabling it we can see the Interactive Preview button beside the deploy to device option.

Comment: This seems to be missing in latest Android Studio Canary.

Comment: It's not experimental anymore, but you do have to hover over the top left of the preview: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76082862/6835732